# Help with wireless mic setup

Tags: wireless, radiomics

There have been a couple of discussions about this but none have really covered Micron or Audio LTD which are two systems I am looking at. I need to invest in a decent wireless setup and have two or three choices which will hopefully be in my budget. I know Lectrosonics or Zaxcom are at the top of the list but I just can't afford to go there. 
I am looking at Audio Ltd setups especially the Audio Limited EN2 Dual Diversity kit. http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/audio-limited-dual-diversity-p-634.html
Micron was also another choice with the 100 explorer series http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/micron-explorer-series-16ch-sdr116-tx716a-p-382.html
Also kinder to the wallet would be the Sennheiser G3 wireless which seem to have mixed opinions on here.
Any advice or sharing of experiences with these systems would be a great help.

Answer (score 3):

I am very happy with the Sennheiser G3s, just spend a bit of time hunting for clear bandwidth and then use fresh Duracells.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Micron Explorer 100 series wireless, and have to say they sound really good. I used sennheiser g2 500 systems before and they were really noisy. I have one G3 500 IEM system and while the sound quality is better than the g2 systems, i think that microns will be a better investment if you want to do this professionally. The range of my systems is way better than g2 systems, usually i get a 30-50 meters of range. Depends on the area of course. Microns have only basic features, no scanning but are built to last and easy to use. It depends how much you want to spend, i bought mine used but in very good shape. You could ask John @ Pinknoise at used kits. I got mine from him also. I'm sure Audio LTD EN2 is a nice system and it has the scan feature as i see.There is another system worth considering -the company is called Audio Wireless - http://www.audiowireless.co.uk/ I do not know the pricing, as it's the new thing, but i heard that they are manufactured by the guy that founded Micron, it may be worth checking out. You could also ask soundies on jwsoundgroup forum.

Answer (score 1):

Can You rent them both and try out first?

There is only one issue with the Microns:
You need to take care of metal touching the case, even the belt clip should not touch the case.To be on the safe side, just by the leather cover for it and You´ll never have any problems with ´em. Although a lot of "theorists" (seller) say, they´re aren´t that good, I used them more than 100 times and never had problems! Better radio frequency stability than G3 .

You might get more possibilities with G3, depends if You need versatility.
Radio -Frequency- slection wise, If You leave Your country ;-)
Frequency wise, if You ever want to transmit signal with bass (mixer to camera etc.)

My
0.2 cents

Comment: Useful to know that I can use the G3 abroad more easily, thanks

Comment: Wow, this problem still hasn't been solved, I stopped using Microns in the 1990's just because of this exact problem.  There also used to be problems with static build up from synthetic clothing, so you had to make sure that the transmitters were encased in a cotton bag.

Comment: Sorry folks for answering this late, was living under a stone for a while ....

I can second the static issue, not only with the Microns, 
had it with all manufacturers preferably using more metal than plastic. audio ltd. , lectronics, etc.
i still think the microns are a good value for it´s price...
if I would have to much money, I´d go with some lectrosonics... 

